# How can I remove part of an URL using Perl?

Tags: perl, url

How can I remove a substring from a string using Perl? For example, `$URL` contains `http://xyz.com/Main#abcd.aspx`

And I want to check and strip out '`Main#`' from `$URL` Can anyone help me out?

Well first I need to check that whether the string `Main#` exist or not.
If it exists, then strip it; otherwise nothing needs to be done. So only an if statement.

Comment: Next time, *don't* community wiki the question. Thats not what it is for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @KentFredric this seems I was right making this a community wiki question, since this is a basic question, viewed by millions now !!

Comment: No. SO editors can still edit any question they have permission to. Lots of viewers doesn't mean anything in terms of "is it wikiable".

It is a finite question, and there are finite, non-subjective right answers. Thus, it is not really "wiki" material.

"I'll make this a wiki" was a bit of an "I'm new here, this sounds like a good idea" newbie mistake in 2009.

Comment: It was such a bad thing, they got rid of the option in 2010: "3 Since October 2010, there is no community wiki checkbox when asking a question."

Comment: @KentFredric agreed that CW was a bad choice for SO. Your definition of a "wiki" material is not correct. Lots of viewers/notable question does mean it is a basic question which people had searched to find the answer, which can be collaboratively edited by the community for a better approach. I don't see questions which are in-finite like "What version of perl do you use?" is a "wiki" material, even if that was meant to be a CW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI::Split qw( uri_split uri_join ); 

my $str = "http://xyz.com/Main#abc.aspx"
my ($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag)  = uri_split( $str );
```

That will give you the URI as a series of tokens, but beyond that, the specifics of what you want to do are a bit unclear.

1. Are you trying to extract the Path so you can use it?
2. Are you trying to recompose the URI without a path?
3. Are you trying to extract only a specific node in the path?
4. Are you trying to recompose the URI without a specific node in the path
5. Are you trying to filter out only the literal string 'Main' , not anything else?

> Well first i need to check that
>   whether the string #Main exist or not,
>   if it exist then strip it otherwise
>   nothing to be done, so only an if
>   statement

```
if( $str  =~ /#Main/ ){
   $str =~ s/#Main//g;
}
```

This will remove the literal string '#Main' from anywhere in the url if it exists. This could also just be written as

```
$str =~ s/#Main//g;
```

Because if it doesn't exist, no replacements will be done.

### Notable Complications

If you are trying to retrieve a URI from a web-client, as in, it is a request string, you'll likely find the `#.*` part, also known as the document fragment, is already removed from the URI when you get it. This is how in my experience web-clients behave.

I'm pretty sure there's an RFC somewhere specifying this to behave like this, but lazyness--

Answer (score 2):

```
$URL =~ s/Main#//;
```

Which is a no-op if "Main#" isn't present.

Answer (score 1):

'perldoc perlop' -- look in the s/// section
'perldoc perlre'' -- read the entire document
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001322/

Answer (score -1):

```
$URL =~ s/Main#//;
```

will strip out the first instance of Main#.   Adding g after the last / will make it strip out all instances.  Stripping out the last instance is less trivial; here are a couple of ways:

```
$URL = reverse($URL);
$URL =~ s/#niaM//;
$URL = reverse($URL);
```

or

```
$URL =~ s/^(.*)Main#/$1/;
```

or

```
my $index = rindex( $URL, 'Main#' );
if ($index >= 0) { substr( $URL, $index, 5, '' ) }
```

If you want to do more complex things (like strip out "com" everywhere except in the hostname) you may want to parse the URI with the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI) or [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI::Split) modules.